# Write trigionemtric series on exponential form

Tags: summation, trigonometric-series

I have $b_k=\frac{1}{k(ln[1+k])^2}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. We have the triginometric series:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k\sin(kx),$$
and has to show that the sum is odd, and write on exponential form. That the sum is odd is because $\sin(kx)$ is odd, and the sum of odd products must be odd

However, I have a hard time writing it on exponential form, but have come to the following, but I don't know if it is correct:
$$b_k=i(f_k-f_{-k})$$
$$\frac{b_k}{i}=f_k-f_{-k}$$
We can see that $a_k=0$ from the sum above, so
$$0=a_k=f_k+f_{-k}\quad\quad\Rightarrow\quad\quad f_k=-f_{-k}$$
So I have:
$$\frac{b_k}{i}=2f_k,$$
which gives:
$$f_k=\frac{b_k}{2i}$$
so the exponential form becomes:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_ke^{ikx}$$

I don't know how to verify whether it is correct.

Comment: In the very last expression the summation should start at $k = 1$ and not $k = 0$. Otherwise it is correct. What kind of verification do you want? This derivation is simple as it is.

Comment: I had tried to find the sum with tools as Mathematica, however, I have failed to verify that the sum should give the same - so I was not able to verify whether the steps were made correctly. Thank you for the help.